# undefined alphabet of observations in HMM

Tags: algorithm-analysis, machine-learning

how to represent an observation matrix if we do not have a defined observation alphabet?
I'm working on extraction of data in a text.

Comment: You mean you have a text but no alphabet?

Comment: Yes .. my text is a code source and I want to extract the name of function,but those names haven't a define alphabet

Comment: Maybe I don't understand because I know nothing about text recognition. But how can you have text without having an alphabet (assuming an alphabetic language, rather than something like Chinese)? Are you trying to do text recognition without knowing a priori what alphabet the text is written in? Could you add more to your question to clarify it? Usually, questions that can be properly asked in a couple of lines are pretty easy to answer from standard resources, whereas more complex questions tend to need more detail.

Comment: Please edit the question to provide additional context.  It's hard to understand what your situation is, what you're trying to accomplish, and what your question is, exactly.  Also, separately: Why do you think that a HMM is the right approach?  Why do you think it's even possible to use a HMM if you don't know the alphabet?